# Proving that a sequence is Cauchy on the basis of squeeze theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $$|x_n| \leq \frac{2n^2 + 3}{n^3 + 5n^2 +3n + 1}$$ Prove $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence

Proof: Suppose that ${x_n}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $|x_n| \leq \frac{2n^2 + 3}{n^3 + 5n^2 +3n + 1}$. 
Then    $-\frac{(2n^2 + 3)}{(n^3 + 5n^2 +3n + 1)}  \leq x_n  \leq \frac{2n^2 + 3}{n^3 + 5n^2 +3n + 1}$.
Now take limit of $\frac{2n^2 + 3}{n^3 + 5n^2 +3n + 1}$ as $n$ approaches infinity. Then $\frac{(2n^2 + 3)}{(n^3 + 5n^2 +3n + 1)}$ approaches zero for big n. Then by squeeze theorem $x_n$ approaches zero too. Thus, it is convergent, therefore Cauchy.
Is my proof ok? Please give me any feedback.

Comment: Your argument looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let denote $(a_n)$ the sequence given by the fraction such that

$$|x_n|<a_n$$
and since
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$$
then by the squeeze theorem we see that $(x_n)$ is also convergent to $0$ hence it's a Cauchy sequence as every convergent sequence is a Cauchy sequence.